# How to set up selection of language for a user with Entity Framework code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm adding the ability to select a language for a user and a company in an existing Entity Framework code first application, and I'm not quite sure how to best go about it.

This is an example of the kind of scenario I want:

> **All available languages in the system:** English, German, French,
>   Spanish, Portuguese, Italian, Dutch, Danish, Swedish and Norwegian
>
> **Company A:** English, German and French are available, English is
>   default.
>
> **Company B:** Spanish, Portuguese, Italian and English are available,
>   Italian is default.
>
> **User X:** Belongs to Company A, so English, German and French are
>   available. When the user was created English was set to their selected
>   language (as it's the default language for the company), but the user
>   has selected French as their selected language instead.
>
> **User Y:** Does not belong to any company. English and French are
>   available, English is selected.

I've created the entities like this (additional properties removed for brevity):

```
public class Language
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string LanguageCode { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
    public ICollection<Language> AvailableLanguages { get; set; }
    public Language DefaultLanguage { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public ICollection<Language> AvailableLanguages { get; set; }
    public Language SelectedLanguage { get; set; }
}
```

This gives me a Languages table containing Id, LanguageCode, Name, CompanyId and UserId, which is fine for mapping companies and users to languages, but it doesn't give me anywhere to store the master list of languages. Do I need to create a separate entity for this to work, or what would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Does the list of available languages change depending on what user or what company it is? Or is the available languages simply a lookup table?

Comment: I need both - there is a master list of all languages, and then when you create a company/user you select which languages are available for them.

Comment: Is 'DefaultLanguage' and 'SelectedLanguage' part of 'AvailableLanguages' or are they separate.

Comment: I've updated with an example, hope that makes it clearer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description indicates that the relationships between `Language` and `Company` and between `Language` and `User` (with respect to the `AvailableLanguages`) are actually many-to-many relationships: A language can be available in *many* companies and a company can have *many* available languages - and the same for users.

In order to achieve many-to-many relationships you can leave the model as is but add a mapping with Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
    .HasMany(c => c.AvailableLanguages)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(m =>
    {
        m.ToTable("CompanyLanguages");
        m.MapLeftKey("CompanyId");
        m.MapRightKey("LanguageId");
    });

modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(u => u.AvailableLanguages)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(m =>
    {
        m.ToTable("UserLanguages");
        m.MapLeftKey("UserId");
        m.MapRightKey("LanguageId");
    });
```

That will give you *five* tables now, the three entity tables and two additional link tables for the two many-to-many relationships. `Language` doesn't contain any foreign keys anymore and becomes the master language table you have in mind.

I don't see in your model how you would handle the situation that an additional language gets added to the list of available languages of a company. Do you want to update then the available languages for every user that belongs to the company? A better solution might be to give the user just a reference to a company (instead of his own list of available languages) and select the user's available languages from his company when you need it. The case that users do not belong to any company at all could possibly be solved by defining a special company "Anonymous company" or so that those users belong to.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I left for the weekend before reading it. This works great, thank you so much! Good point about the updating of languages, however at the moment they want to be able to override an individual user's languages so they need their own set.

Comment: Also, there's a tiny error in the code, it's m.ToTable instead of m.Table.